# Set stack background color in expo-router

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I am getting white flashes as I navigate in a stack, even though I set `backgroundColor` to `#000000`in app.json.

I used `npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50` to create a fresh install, but no dice.

This doesn't work either:

```js
import * as SystemUI from 'expo-system-ui';
SystemUI.setBackgroundColorAsync("black")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a problem with app.json, rather some underlying component having the `backgroundColor` set to `#fff`.

I would suggest checking all the components, that they are respecting dark mode, or do not have explicitly set the white background, eg. `_layout.tsx, +html.tsx, etc.`.

Note: You can see as you're navigating white screens on the side.